# iOS Swift Popup View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I need to have a ViewController slide up, be centered, and overlay the current ViewController.  I thought the following code would work but it does not:

```
let view = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("castSpell") as! CastSpellViewController
view.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
presentViewController(view, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The new ViewController is shown but just as a full screen view.  I have it's size set to 400x300 in the storyboard.  I know I can do the same thing by having a view within a view and then showing the overlay view.  Is that the route I need to go?

Comment: Is this for iOS 7 or for iOS 8?

Comment: It's iOS 8.  I actually figured out a way to do it by using a Popover and setting the arrows to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the presentation style on the *presenter*, not the *presenting* view.

Use `self.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext`

Comment: My code now looks like this but it still does the same thing: let view = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("castSpell") as! CastSpellViewController
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext presentViewController(view, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Revert back to the original code and add `self.definesPresentationContext = true`

Answer (score 0):

```
let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerName") as! PopOverViewContoller
self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
popOverVC.view.frame = self.containerView.frame
self.containerView.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
popOverVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Use the above code to add viewcontroller as a popover view. The container view is optional. I like using container views when the subviews position is fixed. I can position the container using autolayout and keep it hidden until needed.

In you case, you can place the container/subView at the bottom of the screen from where you need to slide up the subview.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
     //Animate here
}
```

Then change the frame of the container/subview inside the above block of code.

Note : Container view is just a normal UIView. I like naming it container :)